# Uniswap V3, calculate volume to reach target price

Tags: uniswap

Given a pool with one or more liquidity positions, is there an efficient algo to compute the swap volume required to hit a target price?

For example, consider a stable token with algorithmic rebalancing and plenty of working capital. As the price drifts away from 1:$1, long or short swaps could nudge the price back to the peg, assuming the trading bot has sufficient capital.

How would the bot compute the volume for the order?

Comment: You need a while loop, iterating over potentially multiple tick ranges. I have code for this somewhere, but it's not publicly shared.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like a function per tick, and iterating over the ticks. I'd love to find an example somewhere.

Comment: I asked the project and they agreed to share the high-level proof of concept code for this. I'll post that in my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume a pool with X and Y assets (order is important). If the current price of X is lower than the target price, then some X assets must be bought from the pool. Otherwise if the price of X is higher than the target price, some Y assets must be bought from the pool.

The basic idea is to compute the amounts of X or Y to buy, with an algorithm similar to the swap algorithm in the Fig. 4, [Uniswap v3 whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf).

Basic idea:

1. Initialize a `delta` variable to zero.
2. Iterate over all tick ranges until the target price is reached:

   1. If the target price is in the considered tick range, calculate the
      number of tokens required to reach that price, add that to `delta`,
      and break the loop.
   2. Otherwise, add all tokens in the tick range to the `delta` (find that by looking at its liquidity), and switch to the next tick range.

The main logic is symmetrical for buying X and buying Y, but implementation details are slightly different depending on which direction the price must move.

Let's assume that these variables are already initialized:

- `contract` - the pool's contract
- `sCurrentPrice` - sqrt of the
  current price
- `sPriceTarget` - sqrt of the target price
- `liquidity` - the liquidity in the current tick range of the pool
- `tickLower`, `tickUpper` - the min and max ticks of the current tick range
- `sPriceUpper`, `sPriceUpper` - square roots of prices
  corresponding to the min and max ticks of the current range
- `tickSpacing` - the tick spacing in the pool.
- `decimalsX`, `decimalsY` - the number of decimals of the X and Y tokens, for   printing the result

What follows is a proof-of-concept Python code.

Let's define some helper functions first:

```
# amount of x in range; sp - sqrt of current price, sb - sqrt of max price
def x_in_range(L, sp, sb):
    return L * (sb - sp) / (sp * sb)

# amount of y in range; sp - sqrt of current price, sa - sqrt of min price
def y_in_range(L, sp, sa):
    return L * (sp - sa)

def tick_to_price(tick):
    return 1.0001 ** tick
```

The main code:

```
from web3 import Web3
from collections import namedtuple

Tick = namedtuple("Tick", "liquidityGross liquidityNet feeGrowthOutside0X128 feeGrowthOutside1X128 tickCumulativeOutside secondsPerLiquidityOutsideX128 secondsOutside initialized")

# how much of X or Y tokens we need to *buy* to get to the target price?
deltaTokens = 0

if sPriceTarget > sPriceCurrent:
    # too few Y in the pool; we need to buy some X to increase amount of Y in pool
    while sPriceTarget > sPriceCurrent:
        if sPriceTarget > sPriceUpper:
            # not in the current price range; use all X in the range
            x = x_in_range(liquidity, sPriceCurrent, sPriceUpper)
            deltaTokens += x
            # query the blockchain for liquidity in the next tick range
            nextTickRange = Tick(*contract.functions.ticks(tickUpper).call())
            liquidity += nextTickRange.liquidityNet
            # adjust the price and the range limits
            sPriceCurrent = sPriceUpper
            tickLower = tickUpper
            tickUpper += tickSpacing
            sPriceLower = sPriceUpper
            sPriceUpper = tick_to_price(tickUpper // 2)
        else:
            # in the current price range
            x = x_in_range(liquidity, sPriceCurrent, sPriceTarget)
            deltaTokens += x
            sPriceCurrent = sPriceTarget
    print("need to buy {:.10f} X tokens".format(deltaTokens / 10 ** decimalsX))

elif sPriceTarget < sPriceCurrent:
    # too much Y in the pool; we need to buy some Y to decrease amount of Y in pool
    currentTickRange = None
    while sPriceTarget < sPriceCurrent:
        if sPriceTarget < sPriceLower:
            # not in the current price range; use all Y in the range
            y = y_in_range(liquidity, sPriceCurrent, sPriceLower)
            deltaTokens += y
            if currentTickRange is None:
                # query the blockchain for liquidityNet in the *current* tick range
                currentTickRange = Tick(*contract.functions.ticks(tickLower).call())
            liquidity -= currentTickRange.liquidityNet
            # adjust the price and the range limits
            sPriceCurrent = sPriceLower
            tickUpper = tickLower
            tickLower -= tickSpacing
            sPriceUpper = sPriceLower
            sPriceLower = tick_to_price(tickLower // 2)
            # query the blockchain for liquidityNet in new current tick range
            currentTickRange = Tick(*contract.functions.ticks(tickLower).call())
        else:
            # in the current price range
            y = y_in_range(liquidity, sPriceCurrent, sPriceTarget)
            deltaTokens += y
            sPriceCurrent = sPriceTarget
    print("need to buy {:.10f} Y tokens".format(deltaTokens / 10 ** decimalsY))
```

The main result is stored in the variable `deltaTokens`, as value with then can be used in the `exactOutputSingle` function call.

A caveat: the approach loops through all tick ranges until the target price is reached. This is fine in most situations, but this approach could be quite inefficient. Looking at the next initialized tick would be more efficient *if* the price difference is big and most of the potentially initialized ticks are not initialized. Another problem is that if there isn't enough liquidity in the pool, the loop would never stop, as there are no other stopping conditions at the moment.

**Edit**: for JavaScript and TypeScript apps, I suggest using the `SwapMath` library from the [Uniswap v3 SDK](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/overview) as the basis for your code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I really appreciate the detailed solution.

Comment: Hmm, maybe there's a hug in your solution or maybe I don't understand. Why the calculations for x_in_range would differ that much from y_in_range?  It looks like the calculations for x take into account that the initial currency price could be between the bounds and should only add a portion of the liquidity